# Omission of "be verb"

Tags: sentence-construction, gapping

A wettable surface may be termed hydrophilic, and non-wettable surface may be termed hydrophobic. Can I rewrite this sentence in the following way?

> A wettable surface may be termed hydrophilic, and a non-wettable surface hydrophobic.

Is the above sentence right? I have another query about the usage of **as** in the above sentence. If I introduce an **as** in the above sentence, please tell me what will happen.

> A wettable surface may be termed **as** hydrophilic, and a non-wettable surface can be termed **as** hydrophobic.

Is the usage of **as** in the above sentence wrong? If it is wrong, please let me know why it is wrong.

Comment: I think it is OK. *termed* is giving a name. No relationship (what *as* would do) is needed. Also no need to repeat *termed* in the second phrase.

Answer (score 3):

What I enjoy most about the first sentence is its *economy of words*. It *could* be trimmed even further via, "...and non-wettable surfaces hydrophobic." But that is six of one and a half dozen of the other.

The second sentence is fine albeit a bit clunky. If it comes down to preference, I always side with the clearly understood sentence using the least amount of words.